# Cane someone please give examples of correlations that indicate, with other mechanisms, causation?

Tags: correlation, causality

My title basically says it all. Can somebody please give some good, interesting examples of correlations with causation? The causation need not be confirmed. It just need to be debatable, plausible stuff.
Edit: Okay,I don't think I clearly explained what I am looking for. I am a student and am learning how to create causal arguments based off of correlations only, and my own opinions. That's why I was kind of vague.

Comment: To use Gould's epistemiologic term: correlation and causation are non-overlapping magisteria.

Comment: Almost everything is an example. If two variables are correlated, then there's a causal structure making it so. X could affect Y, Y could affect X, they could affect each other, or something else is affecting both. This is called Reichenbach's common cause principle and there's a debate whether there are counterexamples to it, but it's safe to say that it's a good working assumption. We see patterns (sample correlations), we wonder whether they generalise (model/population correlations) and if they do, how they come about (causation/science).

Comment: https://www.motherjones.com/kevin-drum/2017/05/unleaded-gasoline-reduces-violent-crime-sweden-too/ , plus a bunch of the earlier work on lead and crime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, correlations *by themselves* can *never* "indicate" causation. There always needs to be some plausible mechanism.

But simple examples abound. For instance, in my line of work, we observe that promotions in your local supermarket typically correlate with higher sales. We believe strongly enough that there is some kind of causation underneath that we use information about future promotions to improve forecasts for future demands (so we can stock up in advance). It seems to work so far.

There are other correlations between health care expenditures on the one hand, and GDP, life expectancy and infant mortality, on the other hand [here](https://ourworldindata.org/health-meta#health-returns-to-healthcare-investment).